# SMTP error: "Client does not have permission to submit mail to this server"

Tags: c#, smtp

I'm getting the following error while sending email.  What could be the cause?

> Client does not have permission to
>   submit mail to this server. The server
>   response was: 5.5.1 STARTTLS may not
>   be repeated.

Here's the stack trace...

Stack Trace

```
at System.Net.Mail.StartTlsCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
at System.Net.Mail.StartTlsCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

I'm connecting to smtp.gmail.com with SSL on port 587 / 465

Comment: It’s impossible to answer without knowing more about the problem. (Other than the obvious answer: don’t repeat STARTTLS.) Post a log of the SMTP dialog up to that point. Remove any real e-mail addresses or server names, of course.

Comment: What kind of log? This is all that comes on the log...it is unable to go beyond the smtp server to send email

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t see your stack trace at first. It looks like you’re working at a higher level and not doing the low-level SMTP transaction yourself. So, as Brent Pabst suggests, the sending code would be more helpful than an SMTP log (which you may not have in this case).

Comment: I can verify that I've also gotten this error from gmail - looking into it...

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using an SSL/TLS connection to send the mail message, however it appears for some reason that the code is sending the request to open the connection twice which is not valid.  Hard to tell just from the exception and stack what the problem is.  Post the sending code if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the SMTP server requires authentication (username / password) and you don't supply them? 
(Just a guess)